# Multiple Fragment To Single Actitvity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I don't know how to express this, but the idea was I have a Navigation Drawer that will call (Intent an Activity) and that `Activity` will automatically replace the content base from the `NavigationView` link click.

So from my MainActivity -> ReadActivity (Activity call other Activity) and replace the ReadActivity content with the topic click from the `NavigationView` .

This code I use for replacing:

```
LayeringViewer layeringViewer = new LayeringViewer();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.layer_frame_layout,layeringViewer);
ft.commit();
```

I know how to place a fragment. But how can I do this while calling other Activity? Passing the Fragments like Bundles.

[image: sample]

Comment: If you start a new Activity, you lose the Fragment container view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to change the content according to selection from drawer, then **pass data on drawer close to activity** and according to that replace fragments

Ex:

```
Fragment fragment = new SupportFragment();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putInt(SupportFragment.ARG_NAME, name);
  args.putString("screenfrom", screenfrom);
  fragment.setArguments(args);
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: do you get this ? you can ask if in confusion.@RoCk

Comment: Yes, I will try. And will accept your answer. Thanks Amit.

Comment: Nope but I modified it. I didn't use Bundle. But similar to that I just past a String as a keyword and when receive from other I get the keyword then put it inside the switch statement to change the frame_layout_placeholder. I found it useful your answer what bugs me the ARG_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass fragments in bundles, you can however send extras with your intent and in the receiving activity get the intent and replace the fragment container with a fragment based on the value of the intent.

Comment: can you give me a hint code? I can picture out your idea.